# C# запуск NodeJs через Process

Tags: javascript, c#, cmd, консоль, процесс

Мне нужно запустить nodejs, перехватив его потоки ввода и вывода. Я написал код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c node";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        p.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        p.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        p.Start();

        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.BeginErrorReadLine();

        var stdin = p.StandardInput;
        stdin.WriteLine("console.log('test');");
        stdin.Flush();

        p.WaitForExit();
        p.Close();

    }
}
```

При этом сам nodejs запускается, но ввод/вывод не перехватывается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При этом если выполнить в другом cmd комманду taskkill /f /im node.exe окно закроется...

Если закомментировать строку, с параметрами для cmd

```
//p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c node";
```

То все нормально работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Правка**
C потоком ввода/вывода все впорядке. Если указать файл js, который должен запускаться, то его вывод перекинется
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c node run.js";
```

В файле run.js:

```
console.log('lol');
```

А есть ли у node.js параметр, который принудительно запускает окошко с > ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Гораздо удобнее и правильнее вместо этого сделать `p.StartInfo.FileName = "node.exe";`

Comment: Нет, Qwertiy, не удобнее. Так придется указывать абсолютный путь к бинарнику, он не подцепится из PATH

Comment: @ТрипольскийПётр а в серьезном проекте вам путь к бинарнику будет нужен в любом случае. Просто потому что ноды в PATH может и не быть, а работать - надо.

Comment: @ТрипольскийПётр, у меня работает из %path%: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSvPP.png. Возможно дело в том, что этих переменных две - пользовательская и глобальная? Ещё обращаю внимание, что я написал `node.exe`, а не просто `node` - уже сталкивался с [похожими проблемами](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46195976/4928642).

Comment: @Qwertiy Хм, вижу. Тоже проверил, да, подцепит из path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто надо было использовать ключ -i

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c node -i";
```

[image: скриншот]